# Unable to create relationship with non-persisted nodes. Neo4jRB Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j, neo4j.rb

I'm trying to create a blog, and associate a comment to a post.

The way I'm defining the relations is as follows:

```
#post.rb
has_many :in, :comments, origin: :post # 5.03 try sth else
```

---

```
#comment.rb
has_one :out, :post, type: :comments_on
```

The error I'm getting is the following.

```
Neo4j::ActiveNode::HasN::NonPersistedNodeError in CommentsController#create
Unable to create relationship with non-persisted nodes
```

Application Trace:

```
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:27:in `new'
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:27:in `create'
```

Framework Trace:

```
neo4j (5.0.2) lib/neo4j/active_node/has_n.rb:185:in `validate_persisted_for_association!'
neo4j (5.0.2) lib/neo4j/active_node/has_n.rb:350:in `block in define_has_one_setter'
neo4j (5.0.2) lib/neo4j/shared/property.rb:55:in `block in send_props'
neo4j (5.0.2) lib/neo4j/shared/property.rb:55:in `each'
neo4j (5.0.2) lib/neo4j/shared/property.rb:55:in `send_props'
neo4j (5.0.2) lib/neo4j/shared/property.rb:25:in `initialize'
neo4j (5.0.2) lib/neo4j/active_node/property.rb:7:in `initialize'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:553:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:84:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Request:
Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"nbc5AbgDSLmbt0Rh2FjYfQxuq8/N8jbNtfwPr28cSC+VUjK9YHZYWqx5e5LyZe7uNU8f2msFisLwaT+pgLDn3w==",
 "comment"=>{"body"=>"comment body",
 "post"=>"b4a6dd87-cb67-46fb-b26a-147065fce038"},
 "commit"=>"Create Comment"}
```

I'm following the introductory video for creating a blog with Neo4jrb gem and rails. [Neo4j ruby gem intro screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDjbqRL9HcM&list=PLswNfthAxTDFXL8kVrOJka5Kpw0z158cx)

I've found a similar issue on [github](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/566), but I'm not sure if this the same problem.

The problem seems to be on creating the relations, am I no defining the relation correctly, any suggestions ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `Neo4j::Config[:autosave_on_assignment] = true` in `applicaton.rb` fixed the issue.

You can see the full issue-answer on [Github](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/864#issuecomment-121313619).

Comment: A few days ago, a change was merged in that provides handling of unpersisted nodes. Check out http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Querying.html#associations-and-unpersisted-nodes. It's in the master branch at the moment, won't be released for a week or two, I imagine.

Comment: Thank you, I 'll have a look.